# Display (Wordpress) Child Pages with Title, Thumbnail and Excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

Apologies in advance for a question, which to an expert, I've no doubt is relatively obvious. I've looked at WordPress Codex for the appropriate information (the_post_thumbnail, the_excerpt, etc) but am not well versed enough in .php yet to implement it properly. Still learning!

I am trying to display, within the  of a standard (WP) page, the child-pages, including their Title, Thumbnail and Excerpt. I can get everything to work bar the THUMBNAIL and EXCERPT with the following:

```
    <div class="child-pages">
    <?php
        $pageChild = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'sort_order' => 'ASC' ) );
            foreach( $pageChild as $page ) { 
    ?>
        <!-- loop: child page -->
        <div class="child">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo '<h3>'.$page->post_title.'</h3>'; ?></a>
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->
            <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url( $page->ID ); ?>">
            <?php echo $page->the_excerpt; ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

So far, I can see the links/titles of the correct child-pages, and in the correct order, but not the Thumbnail or Excerpt. Obviously, I am not calling the Thumbnail or the Excerpt properly. Could someone please correct me?

I have also tried these lines, as supported by the twenty-sixteen theme:

```
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php twentysixteen_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thumbnail doesn't show because the function [`the_post_thumbnail_url();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url) shows the thumbnail of the current post, the parameter is to specify the size of the image, not the post.

`$post->the_excerpt` is not necessarily filled. If you look at the add/edit post screen you'll notice two textfields, one for editing the content of the post and one for the excerpt. The excerpt is optional, so the function `the_excerpt()` shows the content of that field, but when it is empty it will show the first X characters of `$post->the_content`.

Regarding your second attempt: the functions `the_excerpt()`, `get_permalink()` and `twentysixteen_post_thumbnail()` don't work because you don't set up the post properly.

The easiest way would be to add [`setup_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) to your code:

```
$pageChild = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'sort_order' => 'ASC' ) );
foreach( $pageChild as $page ) { 
    setup_postdata( $page ); 
    // now you can use all the fancy functions like `the_excerpt()`
    // add your output here
}
```

Or you can do it the recommended way, using a [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'ASC' 
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerald! Hugely appreciated! I did opt for the 'easy' answer, adding the line 'setup_postdata( $page );' then adding the fancy stuff. I promise I did try the WP_Query technique but couldn't get it to display the child pages - it only brought up my sample blog post. I'm only just learning about the WP_Query tag having used it today for the first time to identify the archive pages of my custom post types and display them like listings in a directory.